# CentOS 5.6 Update Version Of Tar

Tags: centos5, tar

I am running CentOS 5.6 and for some ungodly reason, the version of `tar` is from 2004, and not compatible with the node package manager (NPM). How in the world can I update it? Is there an additional yum repository I can add, so I can simply execute `yum update tar`.

Comment: What version is your current tar and what version do you require?

Comment: Also, tar is an old piece of software and isn't updated often, why do you need a new version?

Comment: @MikeyB Looking at the the CentOS 5.6 FTP site (which seems to be the closest rpm-based distros get to a `packages.` site), it looks like 5.6 has 1.15.1.  My guess is that in 2006 when 1.15.91 changed file globbing to require `--wildcard`, RHEL/CentOS kept the old version rather than changing their programs.

Answer (score 1):

The CentOS6 package fails dependencies on 5.6, so, you probably will need to build it yourself, either nicely packaged or not.  I don't seen an updated "tar" package up at Dag or Karan.

Comment: Which dependencies?

Comment: glibc, so you're not going to be able to easily work around that one.  I just tried a "rpmbuild" on the RHEL6 tar src rpm (GNU tar 1.23), and it's failing because it needs a newer autoconf version.  If you want a packaged installation, your best bet might be to grab the 5.6 SRPM, open it up, and modify the .spec file to use a more recent tar distribution.  Or, you can just do the usual "configure; make install" thing and put the new one in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on my RHEL 5.x system, the package is called `tar.x86_64`. So `yum update tar` will fetch the update if there is one available.

Comment: Yeah that version is way old, I need a newer version, do I have to build from source?

Comment: No, the package from yum will have the same name. Use `yum info tar` to see the new version that will be available. Also remember that RHEL and Centos are conservative with their package selection, as a result, they don't ship the most recent packages.